# Can "It is a shame that ~." and "It is a pity that ~." be used to describe the feeling when in a soccer game our ball misses the target by an inch?

Tags: idioms

I wonder whether I can use the expressions, "It is a shame that ~." and "It is a pity that ~." when during a soccer match our ball misses the target by a tiny distance.

For example, can I say "It is a shame that our ball missed the target by a tiny distance! We almost scored!" or "It is a pity that our ball missed the target by a tiny distance! We almost scored!"?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a very restrained and formal way of expressing it. Most of us would just curse.

Comment: "It's too bad that No. 7 missed his shot" is more colloquial.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. Your comment was very helpful but can you also regard the question again that I made a little bit of change to? :)

Comment: @JohnFeltz I appreciate your comment. Thank you. But I think I wonder about something slightly different from it so I made a change to the question.

Comment: Same thing applies.  "It's too bad the the ball missed the goal..."  Whether you use active voice (emphasizing the player) or passive voice doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @JohnFeltz Can you focus on the fact that the ball passed just an inch from the target area? Imagine it were very close. So you feel something from your heart and I would like to know an expression decribing that. :)

Comment: @SmartHumanism you should edit the question accordingly.  As worded, you are merely asking if "it was a shame/pity" are correct.  Does the word "heartbroken" convey the meaning you want?

Comment: "_It's a bummer!"_

Comment: _Dang that was close!_ (Or, as @StoneyB said, a much more emphatic word than _dang_ can be used.)

Comment: @JohnFeltz Thank you for the helps and I am sorry for my question being confusing. I am asking a question whether "It is a shame/pity" is okay to describe the feeling that we get when our ball misses the target by a close distance. Or if there are other good similar expressions. Because it was very close, we cannot just forget the scene for several seconds . And I have received many good answers for that and I appreciate them a lot, but somehow I am not sure if I have got the very answer.

Comment: It's a shame/it's a pity have little or nothing to do with the magnitude of the loss or the closeness of the miss...

Comment: @JohnFeltz I am so sad I don't know how to express it. I would like to know the ways to express my feelings. Maybe from the start of this curiosity, it was not the English way of dealing with the feelings. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these expressions are fine but a little bit [dispassionate](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/dispassionate), as if you don't feel a lot of emotion about the game.  I can't help but imagine a couple of very well-mannered British aristocrats watching the game:

> "Oh that's a shame.  What a pity he missed that shot."
>
> "Indeed."
>
> *(both sip their tea)*

As StoneyB mentions, most people would use much stronger language.  Some *nicer* examples of this:

> Oh my god! He missed the shot!
>
> Can you believe he missed that shot!
>
> How the hell did he miss that shot?
>
> How in the world could he have missed that shot?

And many, many others.

[Edit] As J.R. mentions in his comment, some people (of a calm and civil demeanor) might use different language to respond to the case where the ball just misses the goal.  For example:

> Oh! *So* close!
>
> Almost got it!
>
> Damn! Missed by a hair!

And so on. Now me, I'd still probably issue a string of expletives and say unkind things about the kicker's family.  It really depends on personality.

Comment: I don't think your sentences match the intent of the OP. The OP seems to be talking about a tantalizingly close shot just wide of the post or just above the crossbar. Your sentences seem more appropriate for shots where the player made a bad kick on what was otherwise an open net.

Comment: @J.R. I suppose it depends on the fan.  Many of my friends use pretty colorful language regardless. :)

Comment: Just to be clear, my comment had nothing to do with civility or vulgarity. Someone could just as easily say, “Oh, fuck! He just missed it!” But “How in the world did he miss that?” doesn’t seem like the most fitting thing to say for a narrow miss by a “tiny distance".

Comment: @J.R. I think that you writing "a tantalizingly close shot" show you got my point! Thank you for the caring.

Comment: @Andrew Your answer was awesome and very helpful. Thank you very much for that. :)  But, instead of using certain words describing or related to a specific occasion, I would like to know a more general expression that describes the feeling that comes from such scenes or occasions.

Comment: @SmartHumanism when people watch sports, they can use very creative expressions because of the emotions involved.  For example, when watching (American) football on TV my father-in-law often pounds on the arm of his chair and yells "Get that sucker!" to encourage his team to make a tackle.  So I think you're going to get a hundred different answers, depending on who you ask and how emotional they get about the sport.

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic expression used to describe the event in your question is

> **Near miss**

It might be preceded by a vulgar or polite expletive, e.g.:

> - **Shit! A near miss!**
> - **Bummer! A near miss!**

If the missed goal would have benefitted the side opposed to the speaker's rooting interest, the expression instead would be

> **Close call**

In this case, the vulgar expletive would still be used:

> - **Shit! That was a close call!**

Comment: _Near miss_ is an excellent phrase, but I don’t know if I’ve ever heard that uttered from the stands. More like, "Ooo! That was close!” (where “Ooo” rhymes with “shoe”), or maybe, “Oh, that was **so** close!”

Comment: @P. E. Dant Thank you very much for your answering. I have come to know very useful, concise expression due to you. :)

Comment: @J.R. It may depend upon where in the stands one is seated. In some seats, you would hear nothing but expletive modifying expletive. In fact, having sat amongst sodden hooligans of diverse nationalities at many football matches over the years, I can attest that I've heard nothing _but_ expletives when one's side misses a close one. Not a soul has mentioned shame or pity, in any language, at the sporting events I have attended. The sole exception was at a baseball game in Italy, where it is customary for fans to chant _"Errore! Errore!"_ whenever a fielder boots one.

Comment: P. E. Dant, Sorry to keep bothering you by only asking you but are "close miss" instead of "near miss", and "near call" instead of "close call" possible?   :)

Comment: @SmartHumanism "Near miss" and "close call" are idiomatic expressions. Although we could write "close miss" and perhaps be understood, such a usage would puzzle most readers and listeners.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I sincerly appreciate your answer. Is it same with "near call"? Isn't there any other reason or interpretation about it? For example, there could be a certain reason that "close" does not go along with "miss" in their meanings.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have got to know that "Near miss" and "Close call" are idiomatic expressions such that "Close miss" and "Near call" are not natural and not used ever. But I would like to know if there can be another explanation for that. I am sorry if I am bothering you.

Comment: @SmartHumanism "Near miss" and "Close call" are idiomatic expressions in English. They are natural and in common use, but "close miss" or "near call" will be heard as unnatural and non-idiomatic. There is really no explanation other than to say that  "near miss" and "close call" are idiomatic "set expressions" in English, but that "near" and "close" are not interchangeable components expressing proximity. Similarly, although pie and cake are both baked desserts, we say that an easily accomplished task is "as easy as pie" or "a piece of cake", but not "as easy as cake" or "a piece of pie".